# Why does UIImageView own UIImage. Does it violate MVC principles?

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller, uiimageview, uiimage

One of the main principles of MVC is views should **never** own data. This principle is repeated many times in WWDC Session 116. But then why does `UIImageView` (a view) own `UIImage` (a model)? Doesn't it violate the above principle?

Or do I misunderstand anything here? Maybe just because `UIImageView` has an `image` property doesn't mean it owns that `UIImage`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word *own* is often used just to indicate that one object has retained another. Obviously, a view that displays an image should retain that image for as long as it needs it. But this notion of "ownership" is very limited, and it doesn't mean that the view should be responsible for storing, changing, or otherwise managing the image.

Comment: So it means UIImageView should never directly change the UIImage, leaving that job to a UIController right? Make sense, thanks =)

Comment: But why does UIImageView need to retain the image? It just needs that image the moment it draw itself to screen right?

Comment: UIImageView needs a reference to the image because it may need to redraw itself, and the data it needs to do that is the image. If it doesn't retain the image, then the image could easily be deallocated at any time, and the view would be left with an invalid pointer (and probably crash). It retains the image that it's using until somebody tells it to use some other image instead.

Answer (score 4):

Good question. In my opinion, the UIImageView does not "own" the UIImage, but it obviously needs to have a reference to it. The UIImageView does not instantiate the image.

The same argument could be made for a UILabel (a view) having a text property (a model).

Comment: Why does it need to have a reference to a UIImage? Normally there will be a controller standing between view and model. When the model changes, it will notify the controller, then the controller will tell the view to re-render. But here, UIImageView automatically re-render when its image property is changed. Yes, it really does sound stupid when you have to separate a UILabel and its text property, but this is not the ideal MVC preachs doesn't it?

Comment: In a pure MVC model, the controller will "own" and contain references to both the view and the model. The view will have a reference to the model and know how to display itself. The controller is still responsible for telling the view which model instance to use.

Comment: Agree. But the view doesn't need a model in its ivar list (or property list). It can just have a method like `-(void) renderWithModel:(Model *)m;` - which will be called by the controller when the model is changed right? I totally understand if UIKit makes UIImageView have a image property for performance reason (why needs a controller for such trivial thing), but then it somehow violates the MVC ideal I have in my mind.

Comment: It could, but the view having a reference to the model does not violate MVC principles, at least by most people's definition. The renderWithModel-type methods tend to result in more "procedural" coding. Again, it's more opinion and theory rather than hard and fast rules.

Comment: OK, I must admit I don't have too much experience with MVC, hence this noob question. Do you know if, in other MVC frameworks, it's normal for the view to have references to models? It's okay as long as the view never directly modify those models?

Comment: The controller shouldn't have to worry about when the view needs to render itself. The controller will tell the view: "Here's some data for you to display." The view should remember what or where that data is. UILabel, for instance, might just make a copy of the string it displays. MyContactListView might just retain the array of people it displays instead of copying the whole thing. Same goes for UIImageView.

Comment: I refer to the "Design Patterns" book by the "gang of four" (Gamma/Helms/Johnson/Vlissides). They state: "A view must ensure that its appearance reflects the state of the model" and "each view gets the opportunity to update itself". The "MV" portion of the "MVC" model can also be described as the "Observer" pattern, but that will start a whole new discussion. :)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, a `UIImageView` doesn't own an image, it keeps a reference to the image's *copy* to be able to render it efficiently. `UIImage` just happens to be immutable, so a copy is the same instance as the original.

`UILabel` behaves identically, but explicitly declares its `text` property as `copy`.