# Protocol, delegate and datasource on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, protocols

Model View Controller policy says that views can`t own data and delegate should be used to ask data from the ViewController.

But what about for exapmle UILabel? Controller talks direct to the Outlet, for example:

self.textfield.text=@"Show this text". (There is no delegate here? UILabel is also a kind of view?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does UIImageView own UIImage. Does it violate MVC principles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215891/why-does-uiimageview-own-uiimage-does-it-violate-mvc-principles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegation would be unnecessarily complicated for something simple like setting text in a UILabel.

An example of breaking MVC with a UILabel would be using its text property as the only storage for a piece of data used elsewhere in your app. For example, if the app involves a person's name and other info that are displayed with UILabels, chances are you should have a Person class as part of your Model and not use the UILabels as the exclusive storage for that info.

Comment: The important point, though, is that it's fine for a view to have a copy of or reference to a piece of data, but the view shouldn't care where the data came from, what it means, etc. UILabel is very reusable exactly because it doesn't worry about those things; you give it a string, and it'll display that string until someone tells it to display a different string.

Comment: @Caleb So why does UIPickerView use a datasource for the number of components for example? Surely the number of components can be a copy of or reference to a piece of data and not care where that came from.

Comment: @Ant I'd say that the whole point of using a data source is so that the picker doesn't care where the data comes from. You give the picker a data source -- *any* data source -- and it knows how to ask that object for the items to display. The decision to use a data source for a picker but not for a label is just a matter of design -- do you really want to have to set up a data source for every label? OTOH, do you want to have to ship a boatload of data over to your picker every time a single item changes? They are the way they are because it makes sense w.r.t. how they're used.

Comment: @Caleb. I see, thank you for that. I hadn't realised the point about being able to use _any_ data source. I had almost reached the conclusion that the picker data is unlikely to change over the lifetime of the control whereas a label is more likely to change. I hadn't considered the _amount_ of data involved. I would be very interested in your opinion about the former.

Comment: @Ant I guess it depends on how you use it. A picker is a lot like a table -- the data behind it may or may not change, depending on how you use it. Either way, the control itself only needs the data that's actually being displayed at any given moment, so the data that the control needs changes whenever the user moves one of the picker wheels (or scrolls the table). But FWIW, it's very common to change the content of a picker. For example, choosing an item in the leftmost column may cause the other columns to repopulate completely.

Answer (score 0):

It basically means the `UILabel` should not be modifying the underlying data that supplies the text to be displayed.  Same goes for the controller, which should only act as the bridge from the data to the view.